# I am getting an error when i am running curl - -manual command in my command prompt

Tags: python, windows, curl

When I was try to run `curl --manual` command in my command prompt I am getting an error: *built-in manual was disabled at built-time*

Please help solving this problem of curl command utility. I am facing this problem in Windows

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, This site is for programming questions, not about using common Unix tools. Please check the [help/on-topic] and [ask]. If your curl doesn't have a manual included, did you try the curl website?